How to get rid of link preview when tweeting using X V2 api and Tweepy Library?
I am currently just trying to make a simple tweet of a link, but whenever I run the script and then go and check the X account, the link preview takes up the whole space of the post and I just want to post the link without the preview.....
Anyone know how to get rid of it?
Python code:
import tweepy
#api keys etc.....
response = client.create_tweet(f"you can find more information here https://coinmarketcap.com/")

here is the library
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/API_v2/create_tweet.py
I tried using invisible spaces and abi params by they all yielded an error or just posted with the link preview.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
